# Creating a new txt file from a PowerShell script and writing to it

Tags: powershell

I have a script to run a simple test against my system. I have it using stream reader to read the output in the csv when I run it and erase the CSV it is running from at the end of the test. I am trying to tweak it to create a new file when a test is run that is titled "date-time.txt" and output that specific test into the time stamped .txt file

Here is what I have so far, I am not sure if it is easier to piggyback off this code or make a separate function.

```
$returnValue = Invoke-Expression "C:\example-test.exe -s $serverName -u $username -p $password -c"
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Process the output from the .exe and build our output
#--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
$dateColumn = 0
$failColumn = 4
$stream_reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader{.\example.csv}
$current_line =$stream_reader.ReadLine()
$charArray = $current_line.Split(",")
$testDate = $charArray[$dateColumn]
$failCode = $charArray[$failColumn]
if ($failCode -eq $expectedFailCode) {
    $testResult = "PASS"
}
#build our own csv - test#,pass/fail, date,server,username,password, failcode, expectedFailCode
$outputString = "$testNumber,$testResult,$testDate,$serverName,$username,$password,$failCode,$expectedFailCode"
if ($testResult -eq "FAIL"){
  write-host "$outputString" -ForegroundColor red
} else {
   write-host "$outputString"
}


#must close file
$stream_reader.close()


#must delete npf-audit-csv otherwise we only read the top line every time
#we want it to build a fresh file every time
Remove-Item -Path .\npf-audit.csv -Force
```

Comment: So what is the problem?

Comment: Why don't you use `Import-Csv` for importing the file instead of a streamreader?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is about creating the file with a date as part of the filename ?

I would simply build the file name using `Get-Date -Format` (which returns a string and not a datetime object like regular `Get-Date`), create the new file with `New-Item` and the generated name, and pass the path of the file object returned by `New-Item` to the `StreamReader` :

```
$FileName = (Get-Date -Format "yyMMdd-HHmmss") + ".txt"
$File = New-Item -Type File -Path "." -Name $FileName
$stream_reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader{$File.FullName}
```

I'm assuming a "year month day - hour minute second" format (the `yyMMdd-HHmmss` part), if you want to tweak it I'll let you read [the manual for the `-Format` parameter of `Get-Date`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-7.2#parameters) and [the page on custom datetime formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?view=netframework-4.8).

Comment: Ok, thank you I will try that. But yes creating a file with a date as part of the filename that outputs as a separate entity and does not interfere with the output of the test in the ISE.

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to PowerShell so I worded it as best I could!